# Data-Binding not working in view page - Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, html5-canvas, angularjs-directive, single-page-application

I have shown a simplified version of my problem below:

The directive 'name' is not understood when it is in the view 'loginView.html', however it works fine when It's in the main page 'index.html'

loginView.html

```
<p>Welcome : {{name}}</p>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="name"><br>
<button type="submit" data-ng-click="loginUser()">Login</button>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="vla">
    <head>
        <title>Video Learning application</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>

            <div class = "navBar">
            <div class = "leftButton"></div>
            <div class = "title">VLA</div>
            <div class = "rightButton"></div>
        </div>

            <div data-ng-view=""></div>

            <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
            <script src="controllers/controllers.js"></script>
            <script src="app.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('vla', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider){
           $routeProvider
            .when('/view1',
                  {
                  controller: 'controllers/controllers.js',
                  templateUrl: 'partials/loginView.html'
                  })
           .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });
});
```

controller.js

```
app.controller('loginController', function ($scope)
{
       $scope.loginUser = function () {
               alert("test");
       }

        });
```

The {{name}} just prints itself out when in the view 'loginView', but works fine and prints he contents of the input field when placed into index.html.

I'm very new at this and would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: it is difficult to understand the problem. please create a working sample. for example at plnkr.co

Comment: Do you see any JS errors in the console?

Comment: Is there some sort of ng-".." I have to add to the view pages so the directive is recognised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised the problem was the ordering of the script declarations in the index.php page

The app reference should come before the controller:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/controllers.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write controller name but not path in `controller` option of routeProvider:

```
$routeProvider
   .when('/view1',
       {
          controller: 'loginController',
          templateUrl: 'partials/loginView.html'
       })
       .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });
```

And attach file with controller (`controllers/controllers.js`) with tag `<script>`.

Comment: cheers I corrected it but unfortunately didn't solve my problem. The controller actually does nothing in this instance, I think the problem lies elsewhere